# Чтение файла по n-килобайт

Tags: java

Есть текстовый файл в котором находится одна строка состоящая из рандомных чисел от 0 до 5000 разделенных пробелом, размер этого файла может быть любой.
Как прочитать из этого файла предположим по 100кб создав файл, но так что бы при достижении нужного размера чтение остановилось на пробеле, и повторять этот цикл пока есть что читать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Загоняете файл в InputStream, в цикле читаете предположим по 1024 байт и записывайте их, после достижения нужного размера по условию начинаете читать по одному символу (сколько байт зависит от кодировки), проверяя каждый на пробел.

Comment: Нормально ли будет вместо массива использовать коллекцию в которую записывать байты и при приближении размера коллекции к 100 байтам проверять что бы последний был пробелом или это изврат?

Comment: Коллекция из массива байтов? Ну если только файлы не большие. Это у вас будет сжирать большое количество памяти. Можно читать изначально по количеству байт равному одному символу и после определенного значения проверять что за символ. А с коллекцией я считаю слишком много лишних действий.